# How to change 'paramNames' in gijgo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't change `paramsName` with dijgo. Through the documentation http://gijgo.com/grid/configuration/paramNames.groupBy is be this way. But don't show nothing.

```
function createTable(data) {
  $('#jqGrid').grid({
    dataSource: data,
    grouping: {
      groupBy: 'tipo'
    },
    paramNames: { groupBy: "tipo"},
    icons: {
      expandGroup: '<i class="material-icons">remove</i>',
      collapseGroup: '<i class="material-icons">add</i>'
    },
    columns: [
      {field: 'nome', title: 'Nome', sortable: true},
      {field: 'email', title: 'E-mail', sortable: true},
      {field: 'situacao', title: 'Situação', sortable: true},
    ],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You change the parameter name in the XHR request to the server, when you set value for paramNames.groupBy. That is the right way of doing it. You can monitor what is going to the server tools like 'Developer Tools' for Google Chrome.